# How to compare system's current LocalDateTime with input String date and time

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, localdatetime, datetime-comparison

I am trying to compare the current system's time and date with an input String time and date. I am using `LocalDateTime.now()` to get the systems current time, and also using `DateTimeFormatter` to format it as dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm pattern

```
static DateTimeFormatter frmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
static LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now();
```

Here is what I have:

```
System.out.print("Enter the Appointment new Date and Time as dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm : ");
String dateAndTime = input.nextLine();

if (//dateAndTime is before or equals the current system time)
{
    System.out.println("The new date and time should be after the current time");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Appointment has been updated");
}
```

Comment: Parse `dateAndTime` to a `LocalDateTime`, and then compare it to `time` using `time.compareTo(...)`.

Comment: I've parsed it, how do I compare it then?

Comment: `LocalDateTime` has a `compareTo` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have parsed the input to `LocalDateTime` you can do that as follows:

```java
if (parsedDateTime.isAfter(LocalDateTime.now())) {
    System.out.println("Appointment has been updated");
} else {
    System.out.println("The new date and time should be after the current time");
}
```

Keep in mind that `isAfter` will return false if `parsedDateTime` and `LocalDateTime.now()` are exactly the same.